# Swift problem with percent encoding for local file URL (macOS)

Tags: swift, string, url, path

I have the following issue with a whitespace in a local file path: when setting the file name in an unescaped string, everything works perfectly:

```
var path = "/absolute Path/testfile.txt"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
if let returnstring = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) {
   return returnstring
} else {
    return "could not open"
}
```

However, if I get the filename from

```
fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
```

The whitespace is escaped with percent encoding

````
file:///absolute%20Path/testfile.txt```and the file is not opened anymore.
````

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is that you are getting your fileURL path using the URL `absoluteString` property which contains a scheme and also percent encode to your string. What you need is to get the url `path` property which does NOT contain a scheme and does NOT percent encode your fileURL path.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Since the `currFile.path`property is a string, I changed the constructor to `String(contentsOfFile: currFile.path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` to avoid a back conversion to URL with `URL(fileURLWithPath: currFile.path)`. Works perfectly now!